# Enhanced Ecommerce Not Passing Data To GA

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to get enhanced ecommerce data flowing to GA but after 2 tries, something is missing/not correct with the set up.

Here are screenshots that show the tag is firing, enhanced ecommerce is enabled, and the event is showing in GA - however the purchase event values like revenue etc aren't being recorded in GA.

[tag details values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kmfH.png)

[tag details names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu1K0.png)

[tag configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyNHY.png)

[data layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icnis.png)

[tags fired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGowl.png)

[GA event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fofmx.png)

[ecommerce setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLLht.png)

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the data layer values are not correct, in order to record a transaction, you need to add purchase, not transaction

```
{
   'ecommerce': {
       'purchase': {
         'actionField': {
         'id': 'RL00195',                    
         'affiliation': 'Relish',
         'revenue': '12.99',                    
         'tax':'2.16',
         'shipping': '4.17',
         'coupon': '',
         'currency':'GBP'
      },
      'products': [{                            
          'name': 'Category Snap',    
          'id': 'AB005',
          'price': '6.66',
          'brand': '',
          'category': '',
          'variant': '',
          'quantity': 1,
          'coupon': '' 
      }]
   }
}
```

this should be the data layer values

Comment: Hi Vilsad P P, 'transaction' is what we put for the event name in Tag Manager- does the event name and code need to be updated to be called 'purchase'